# Prove that the MLE $\hat{p}(1-\hat{p})$ is a asymptotically efficient

Tags: self-study, estimation, normality-assumption, asymptotics, efficiency

Consider when $X_1, ..., X_n \sim $ Bernoulli($p$). We want to estimate $p(1-p)$. Suppose $\hat{p}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i$. 
Prove that the MLE $\hat{p}(1-\hat{p})$ is a asymptotically efficient

Here efficient estimator is referring to "any estimator that attain equality of the Cramér-Rao bound asymptotically". In other words for an estimator $T$ we have $   \operatorname{Var}[\,T\,]\ =\ \mathcal{I}_\theta^{-1}$.

Here is my confusion about the problem: We know that MLE estimators are (almost) always asymptotically efficient. Can we just use this fact?

One might also say that, find $v = Var(\hat{p}(1-\hat{p}))$ and using $i = I(p(1-p))$ (Fisher information) find the the efficiency $e=vi$. However I am not aware of straightforward closed forms for $i$ and $v$.

Another idea is to use Delta method and say, we know: 
$$
\sqrt{n} ( p - \hat{p} ) \rightarrow N(0, p(1-p)/n)
$$
then, defining $g(u) = u(1-u)$ and $g'(u) = 1-2u$, and using Delta method we have:
$$
\sqrt{n} ( g(p) - g(\hat{p}) ) \rightarrow N(0, (1-2p)^2{p(1-p)}/n)
$$
So asymptotically  $Var(\hat{p}(1-\hat{p})) = (1-2p)^2{p(1-p)}/n$. Also we know $I_X=nI_{X_1}$. $I_{X_1}( {p}(1-{p}) ) = \mathbb{E} \left[ -\frac{d^2}{dg({p})^2} \log f(X_1) \right] $. However this seems to hard to calculate.

Update: I calculate the fisher information for $p$: 
$
l(p; x) = \ln f(x|p) = x \ln  p +(1-x) \ln  1-p \Rightarrow \\ \frac{d}{dp} l(p; x) = x / p -(1-x) / (1-p) \Rightarrow \\ \frac{d^2}{dp^2} l(p; x) = -x / p^2 -(1-x) / (1-p)^2 \Rightarrow \\ I_{X_1}(p) = \mathbb{E}_x[-l(p; x)] = p / p^2 +(1-p) / (1-p)^2 = \frac{1}{p} - \frac{1}{1-p} = \frac{1}{p(1-p)} \Rightarrow \\  I_{X}(p) = \frac{n}{p(1-p)}  \\ 
$

Using the idea by @Xi'an (in the comments):

$ 
I_{X}(p) = I_X(g(p)) \left( 1-2p \right)^2 $
$$
\Rightarrow 1/I_X(g(p)) = \frac{p(1-p)(1-2p)^2}{n} 
$$
Which would prove the asymptotic efficiency of the estimator as $Var(g(\hat{p}))/I_X(g(p))=1$.

Caution: This is a HW problem. Hints are appreciated.

Comment: Homework problems should normally carry the `self-study` tag. See its [tag wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: In respect of $v$, can you compute either $\text{Var}(\hat{p}^2)$ or $E(\hat{p}^4)$ or some other quantity which is a function of $E(\hat{p}^4)$ and lower order moments (like, say, the fourth factorial moment)?

Comment: I added the tag

Comment: I can calculate both of $Var(\hat{p}^2)$ and $\mathbb{E}(\hat{p}^4)$ (using Delta method) but I don't know where you are going with this.

Comment: a. Could you set the definition of asymptotically efficient as your starting point? It is usually helpful to rely on definitions.

Comment: b. The delta-method gives you the exact asymptotic variance, so there is no need for "approximately" in your last statement.

Comment: c. The information matrix of a one-to-one transform of $\theta$ into $\eta$ is given by $$\left\{\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial \eta}\right\}^{\text{T}} \mathfrak{I}(\theta(\eta))\left\{\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial \eta}\right\}$$ so this solves your last query.

Comment: a. Added. b. Corrected.  c. I see. I added an update. Could you check that? Thanks! :)

Comment: You are forgetting a $1/n$ in there. Since you scale by $\sqrt n$, it cancels.

Comment: Well, for example, Var$(\hat{p}(1-\hat{p}))$=Var$(\hat{p}^2-\hat{p})$=Var$(\hat{p}^2)$+Var$(\hat{p})$-2 Cov$(\hat{p}^2,\hat{p})$, leaving you with a lower order term to sort out.